# Map [Subjective Objective Assessment Plan] SOAP to HL7 - FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir

Hello I am new to HL7 and FHIR , I am currently trying to find best resources to map SOAP [Subjective Objective Assessment Plan] documents into FHIR.

I have attached the example sample of SOAP document :

Key pieces are -> Patient Info, Clinic info, initial examination, goals, objective, assessment, Plan, Patient Problems , Procedures and Consent.

One of the idea is to use ClinicalImpression to do [Subjective, Objective, Assessment, Plan] but the maturity level is 0, are there more mature models that can be used instead? Or any examples on how it is solved at other places?

Also are there any mapping tools or other resources available that can be utilized for this issue?

[Sample Document](https://docs.google.com/a/webpt.com/document/d/1N_VM65MlOf0xcMs73syjQZBsHtsPdeORFOayv3rv17U/edit?usp=sharing)

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective = Observations, Conditions, supported by FamilymemberHistory, Medication*, Immunization, DocumentReference etc.

Plan = CarePlan + a slew of supporting resources

Subjective/Assessment = ClinicalImpression. Yes, the maturity of this is 0. That represents two things:

- the community has no heritage of interoperating with this kind of data
- there's not much wide interest in doing that, compared to everything else.

I think (hope) this will come, after we've sorted out the other areas.

Comment: Thanks @Grahame Grieve I wanted to make sure we look at appropriate resources before we start mapping exercise. Do you know if any tools can help us improve accuracy of our process or is it manual for now?